# Consult don't work how I want

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-4-2-1

I created a refinanciamento and my show doesn't correct.

show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Nome:</strong>
  <%= @funcionario.pessoa.nome %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Matrícula:</strong>
  <%= @funcionario.matricula %>
</p>
```

When I put @funcionario.first.pessoa.nome, it "work" but, ever return the first, I don't wanna this, sure.

My controller:

```
  def show
    @funcionario = Funcionario.pesquisa_cpf(params[:pesquisa_func_cpf]).first
    @refinanciamento = Refinanciamento.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Example, when I register a refinanciamento, my url on show is: /refinancimento/100, this refinanciamento have the values: id: 100, funcionario_id: 2
I need a where that show the funcionario that have this refinanciamento. How I build this consult?

My models are:

```
class Refinanciamento < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :funcionario
(...)

class Funcionario < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :refinanciamentos
(...)
```

I just want show nome and matricula of funcionario that have the refinanciamento created. Thanks!

Comment: "I just want show nome and matricula of funcionario that have the refinanciamento created." You may want to provide some translations to give the reader context.

Comment: Sorry, but my system is in portuguese, because this I don't translate, ok? Is "nome" and "matricula"

Comment: I'm guessing nome is "name", what do you mean by "matricula", "pesquisa_cpf" and "Consult"?

Comment: matricula can be "register"; pesquisa_cpf can be "search_cpf" and consult is consult.

Comment: I believe `consult` is `query`. `pesquisa_cpf` is a method that searches people from their document number.

Comment: I meant: How I build this query?. Pesquisa_cpf is a method, but I guess it has nothing, can remove quietly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Rails is an opinionated framework and assume some patterns to facilitate the developer life, like implementing everything in english, from classes names to attributes. So you are losing too much programming in your native language (You can always I18n everything to translate the texts and stuff, the code should be in english).

Second, and right to the problem, you have an association between `refinanciamento` and `funcionario`. If a `refinanciamento` `belongs_to` a `funcionario`, when you have a `refinanciamento` object, you can use `@refinanciamento.funcionario` and get all of its data like `nome` and `matricula`.

```
def show
  @refinanciamento = Refinanciamento.find(params[:id])
  # Here you can access funcionario's properties like
  # @refinanciamento.funcionario.pessoa.nome
  # @refinanciamento.funcionario.matricula
  # etc...
end
```